# Action App\Http\Controllers\KategoriController@store not defined

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 8, I wanna try to make an input form using Modals.
It's my first try, and I dunno what's wrong I did while I think I already copying the same as the tutorial.

**Error Message**

> Action App\Http\Controllers\KategoriController@store not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\LARAVEL\Workshop\resources\views\back\kategori-produk\tampil.blade.php)

**Category Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Kategori;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class KategoriController extends Controller
{
    // sesi FRONTEND
    public function index()
    {
        $kategoris = \App\Models\Kategori::all();
        return view('front.product',['kategoris' => $kategoris]);
    }

    // sesi BACKEND
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function indexBack()
    {
        $kategoris = \App\Models\Kategori::all();
        return view('back/kategori-produk/tampil',['kategoris' => $kategoris]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
        ]);

        $kategoris = new Kategori;
        $kategoris->nama = $request->input('nama');
        $kategoris->save();
        return back()->with('Success', 'Data Saved');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Kategori  $kategori
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Kategori $kategori)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Kategori  $kategori
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Kategori $kategori)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Kategori  $kategori
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Kategori $kategori)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Kategori  $kategori
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Kategori $kategori)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**Category View Blade**

Also, code "modal form" in here too.

```blade
@extends('back.index')

@section('content')
<main>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1 class="mt-4">Tables</h1>
        <ol class="breadcrumb mb-4">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="index.html">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Tables</li>
        </ol>
        <div class="card mb-4">
            <div class="card-header">
                <!-- Button trigger modal FORM -->
                @auth
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info float-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                    Add
                </button>
                @endauth


                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                            </div>
                            <form action={{ action('App\Http\Controllers\KategoriController@store') }} method="GET">
                                @csrf
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input id="nama" type="text" class="form-control col-md-8 @error('nama') is-invalid @enderror" name="nama" value="{{ old('nama') ?? $kategori->nama ?? '' }}" autofocus>
                                        @error('nama')
                                            <div class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                                        @enderror
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>Nama</th>
                                <th>Act</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        @forelse ($kategoris as $kategori)
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$kategori->id}}</td>
                                <td>{{$kategori->nama}}</td>
                                @auth
                                <td>
                                    {{-- <a href="{{ route('dosens.edit',['dosen' => $dosen->id])}}"
                                        class="btn btn-secondary" title="Edit Dosen">Edit</a>
                                    <form action="{{route('dosens.destroy',['dosen' => $dosen->id])}}"
                                    method="POST" class="d-inline">
                                    @csrf  @method('DELETE')
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger shadow-none btn-hapus"
                                    title="Hapus Dosen" data-name="{{$dosen->nama}}"
                                    data-table="dosen">Hapus</button>
                                    </form> --}}
                                </td>
                                @endauth
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        @empty
                        <strong>Tidak Ada Data ..</strong>
                        @endforelse
                    </table>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</main>
@endsection
```

**Route in web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\KategoriController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ProdukController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('front.welcome');
});

Route::get('/product', [KategoriController::class,'index']);

Route::get('/product-details', [ProdukController::class,'index']);

Route::get('/service', function () {
    return view('front.service');
});
Route::get('/rent', function () {
    return view('front.rent');
});
Route::get('/training', function () {
    return view('front.training');
});
Route::get('/facility', function () {
    return view('front.facility');
});
Route::get('/aboutUs', function () {
    return view('front.aboutUs');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::prefix('/kategori')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\KategoriController::class, 'indexBack']);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, change this form attribute action from  `<form action={{ action('App\Http\Controllers\KategoriController@store') }} method="GET">` to `<form action={{url('getKategorie') }} method="GET">` then name the url in the routes file. Im sure thats where your problem is. As it stands , laravel is looking for that action in the web.php file and is cannot find it. Hence add something like this `Route::get('getKategorie',[KategoriController,'store']);`. Another thing you need to take note of is, you are using a resource controller, hence a `GET http verb` only read the index method not the store method.The store method works with `POST http verb`. Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have used GET for submitting data, GET is used for retrieving data. You should use POST in place of GET. See my code and use it in your form and routes.

**Category Controller**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Kategori;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class KategoriController extends Controller {
    // sesi BACKEND
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    // sesi FRONTEND
    public function index() {
        $kategoris = Kategori::all();
        return view('front.product',['kategoris' => $kategoris]);
    }

    public function indexBack() {
        $kategoris = Kategori::all();
        return view('back/kategori-produk/tampil',['kategoris' => $kategoris]);
    }
    
    public function create() {
        //
    }

    public function store(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
        ]);

        $kategoris = new Kategori;
        $kategoris->nama = $request->input('nama');
        $kategoris->save();
        return back()->with('Success', 'Data Saved');
    }

    public function show($category) {
        //
    }

    public function edit($category) {
        //
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $category) {
        //
    }

    public function destroy($category) {
        //
    }
}
```

**Category View Blade**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('category.store') }}">
    @csrf

</form>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('', 'KategoriController@index')->name('category.index');
Route::get('', 'KategoriController@indexBack')->name('category.indexBack');
Route::get('create', 'KategoriController@Create')->name('category.create');
Route::post('create', 'KategoriController@Store')->name('category.store');
Route::get('show/{category}', 'KategoriController@Show')->name('category.show');
Route::get('update/{category}', 'KategoriController@Edit')->name('category.edit');
Route::patch('update/{category}', 'KategoriController@Update')->name('category.update');
Route::delete('delete/{category}', 'Users\UserController@Destroy')->name('user.destroy');
```